# How to Observe LiveData with custom pair class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata

I am trying to observe the LiveData for the method which returns custom pair having 2 values. I want the observable to be triggered when I change either one of the values. But it is not getting triggered. Following is the code:

CustomPair.kt

```kotlin
data class CustomPair<T, V>(
    var first : T,
    var second : V
)
```

Observable:

```kotlin
falconViewModel.getPlanet1Name().observe(this) {
    planet1.text = it.first
    planet1.isEnabled = it.second
}
```

Getter and setter methods in ViewModel `falconViewModel`

```kotlin
private val planet1EnabledAndText = MutableLiveData<CustomPair<String, Boolean>>()

fun getPlanet1Name() : LiveData<CustomPair<String, Boolean>> {
    return planet1EnabledAndText
}

fun setPlanet1Name(planetName : String, visibility : Boolean) {
    planet1EnabledAndText.value?.run {
        first = planetName
       second = visibility
    }
}
```

Can't we observe the value in such case? Please help what is wrong here.

Comment: You should be setting a new value (i.e. a new `CustomPair`) for `planet1EnabledAndText` rather than trying to modify the members of the existing value.

Comment: @Michael Yes, thanks for the tip. Its working by doing `planet1EnabledAndText.value = CustomPair(planetName, visibility)` .

Comment: I don't recommend using a mutable class in a LiveData. Very error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working when I tried to set a new value of `CustomPair` instead of modifying the existing values in the object.
Replaced

```kotlin
planet1EnabledAndText.value = CustomPair(planetName, visibility)
```

with

```kotlin
planet1EnabledAndText.value?.run {
        first = planetName
       second = visibility
    }
```

and it worked.